# Azure - Gac assemblies

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, gac

Assemblies  version - MySql - Currently I am using MySql.Data.dll version 6.9.9.0 but inside I have seen after published my website, I found gac is having version 6.5.4.0. How can solve this issue in Azure - App service?

Comment: Obvious solution first: set the DLL properties to Copy-Local=true, would that work?

Comment: Okay let me check it Thanks to Henk

Answer (score 0):

As per microsoft's documentaton

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/migration/app-service#assemblies-in-the-gac-global-assembly-cache

the assemblies need to be in bin folder. You may require to do copy local to true.